# Post display in separate page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, blog

I have post my post in two different pages. One is News and the other is Blog. However, all my posts go to News page insead. My Blog is a hidden page, it will not display in the menu. This is more for my SEO purposes.

What I have done:
Created a new category called blog under post button. However, there is nowhere I can link this blog category to my Blog page.

[image]
[image]
Once I create the post, the post will go to spotworks.com.sg/category/blog as well as in the New page. However, I want my blog to display only in spotworks.com.sg/blog

The problem now is how can I show the selected post in my Blog page, or how can I link the category to my Blog page. Also, this will not affect the post in my News page. Really thank you for the people can help me here!

Comment: Research before asking!

Answer (score 0):

As you have two pages to display the posts i.e. News & Blog.

1- All your posts will display in the blog page by default if you didn't do any custom code.

2- To show the posts of selected category on the news page you can use this plugin.

https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/posts-in-page/
Its very easy to use this plugin just select the categories and paste the shortcode on page.

Comment: Really thanks for the reply, just for checking. After I use this plugin, will the post goes to both of the pages?